# Run python in background

Tags: python, linux

I've been searching a lot for this problem, but I didnt find any valuable answer.

I want to make a script (lets say it is a library) which runs some functions at reboot. Inside my library, there will be a function like

```
def randomfunction():
    print("randomtext")
```

After loading this function, everytime a call for randomfunction() in any python run (I will .py as cgi scripts) will return me "randomtext".

Is that possible or I miss something?

---

It is working on python idle if I use exec, but I want this exec to be on system. That would be for a linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need some kind of Interprocess Communication for this?

Might be worth taking a look at these docs: [Python IPC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html)

Also, 
[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761617/python-remote-procedure-call-without-the-remote-part) might help you. I think it offers a solution to what you are looking for.